# How to prove $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)\leq \sum_{j=0}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^j$

Tags: inequality, products

If $a_{i} \geq 0$ , then $(1+a_{1})(1+a_{2})\cdots (1+a_{n}) \leq 1+(a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n})+(a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n})^{2}+\cdots+(a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n})^{n}$

I found it in the book Theory and Applications of Infinite Series.
I was not capable of proving it.
And I love understanding everything while I am studying.

I am studying infinite products from this book.

Comment: HInt: Divide it out into $n+1$ inequalities based on the number of terms. EG $1 \leq 1$, $ a_ 1 + a_2  \ldots \leq (\sum a_i) $, and $a_1a_2 + a_1a_3 + \ldots \leq (\sum a_i)^2$.

Comment: If you expand out the LHS you get the sum of all products of the $a_i$ with no $i$ repeated, while on the RHS you get the sum all products of any $n$ of them including possible repeats. So if you subtract them you are left with the sum of all products of $n$ variables with at least one repeated index, which is nonnegative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We transform the left-hand side of (1)
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)\leq \sum_{j=0}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^j\tag{1}
\end{align*}
until the inequality becomes obvious. In the following we use the notation $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+a_k\right)}
> &=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}\prod_{k\in S} a_k\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{{S\subseteq [n]}\atop{|S|=j}}\prod_{k\in S}a_k\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{{l_1+l_2+\cdots+l_n=j}\atop{l_k\in\{0,1\},1\leq k\leq n}}
> \prod_{k=1}^na_k^{l_k}\tag{4}\\
> &\leq \sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{{l_1+l_2+\cdots+l_n=j}\atop{l_k\geq 0,1\leq k\leq n}}
> \binom{j}{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n}\prod_{k=1}^na_k^{l_k}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^j}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we multiply out the $n$ factors $(1+a_k), 1\leq k\leq n$ and select from them $|S|$ factors $a_k$ with indices $k\in S\subseteq[n]$ and $(n-|S|)$ times the summand $1$ from the factors $(1+a_k)$.
- In (3) we reorder the sum in ascending order by $j$.
- In (4) we use just another representation by selecting $j$ out of $n$ indices which are $1$ and $n-j$ indices which are $0$.
- In (5) we note the multinomial coefficient is a factor $\geq 1$ and each $n$-tuple $(l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n)$ of indices in (4) is also one of the $n$-tuples in the index region of the sum in (5). This explains the inequality sign between (4) and (5).
- In (6) we apply the *[multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)*.

Comment: Very interesting, I feel it's the first time ,I see,  someone indexing the summation by subsets of some set.

Many thanks to you.

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is helpful. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Let $S = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n$.

By AM-GM and the binomial theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS} &\le \left(\frac{1 + a_1 + 1 + a_2 + \cdots + 1 + a_n}{n}\right)^n\\
 &= (1 + S/n)^n\\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (S/n)^k\\
 &\le \sum_{k=0}^n S^k\\
 &= \mathrm{RHS}
\end{align*}
where we use $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!} \le \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \le n^k$.

We are done.